# How to exclude rows with certain words in a query on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTE9p.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GN9r7.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc1bB.png)

Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 have rows that include "Family Total" which I would like to exclude the entire row from the QUERY.

Would like for my query results to look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGT7w.png)

Comment: Pls share a spreadsheet. People are most likely to not help when there is a lot of data involved but only a screenshot is attached. It is like asking them to create a sheet which they need to fill in by themselves (copy the data of your screenshot) then find the solution. Please make it easy for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=QUERY({Sheet1!A1:G11; Sheet2!A1:G11}; "where not Col5 contains 'Family Total'")
```